# Ionic: Provider not resolvable

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem and I couldnt find an anwser so far.

So I have this ionic project with 3 pages and a provider for the api connection.

Scanner.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { QRScanner, QRScannerStatus } from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {StorageProvider} from "../../providers/storage/storage";
import {ApiProvider} from "../../providers/api/api";
import {DocsPage} from "../docs/docs";
import {GlobalvarProvider} from "../../providers/globalvar/globalvar";

//https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-scanner',
  templateUrl: 'scanner.html'
})
export class ScannerPage {

  key : string;

  GlobalvarProvider : any = GlobalvarProvider;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private qrScanner: QRScanner,
              private alertCtrl: AlertController,
              private storage: StorageProvider,
              private api: ApiProvider) {}

  public changeToHomePage(){
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(DocsPage);
    GlobalvarProvider.setPagesConnected();
  }

  textInput(){
    this.api.connectToAPI(this.key);
  }

  scanner(){
    //Testcode: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner/
    this.qrScanner.prepare()
      .then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
        if (status.authorized) {
          // camera permission was granted
          // start scanning
          let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => {
            //Mit API verbinden
            this.api.connectToAPI(text);

            this.qrScanner.hide(); // hide camera preview
            scanSub.unsubscribe(); // stop scanning
          });
          // show camera preview
          this.qrScanner.show();
          // wait for user to scan something, then the observable callback will be called
        } else if (status.denied) {
          // camera permission was permanently denied
          // you must use QRScanner.openSettings() method to guide the user to the settings page
          // then they can grant the permission from there
        } else {
          // permission was denied, but not permanently. You can ask for permission again at a later time.
        }
      })
      .catch((e: any) => console.log('Error is', e));
  }
}
```

If i use the Api Provider on the ScannerPage no error occurs and i can use the Api.

Although using the APi Provider on the DocsPage an Error occurs.

Docs.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiProvider } from "../../providers/api/api";
import {StorageProvider} from "../../providers/storage/storage";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-docs',
  templateUrl: 'docs.html',
})
export class DocsPage {

  items: Array<{title: string}>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private storage: StorageProvider,
              private api : ApiProvider) {
   // this.api.updateResources();
    this.items =[];
  }

  doRefresh(refresher) {
    refresher.complete();
  }

  /*itemTapped(event, item) {
    // That's right, we're pushing to ourselves!
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {
      item: item
    });
  }*/

}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SettingsPage: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15547)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15382)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:14890)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:15695)
    at compiler.js:15165
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15165)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:33542)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:33503).
```

Removing the ApiProvider reference from the DocsPage solves the error, but why can i use the provider without errors on the scannerpage ?

Both Pages use the same modul file from 
app.moduls.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { ScannerPage } from '../pages/scanner/scanner';
import { DocsPage } from "../pages/docs/docs";
import { SettingsPage} from "../pages/settings/settings";

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { QRScanner} from "@ionic-native/qr-scanner";
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { StorageProvider } from '../providers/storage/storage';
import { NativeStorage } from "@ionic-native/native-storage";
import { ApiProvider } from '../providers/api/api';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import { GlobalvarProvider } from '../providers/globalvar/globalvar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ScannerPage,
    DocsPage,
    SettingsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ScannerPage,
    DocsPage,
    SettingsPage,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    QRScanner,
    NativeStorage,
    HttpClient,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    StorageProvider,
    ApiProvider,
    GlobalvarProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you please include the full error prone version of the `DocsPage.ts`

Comment: included full version of DocsPage.ts

Comment: the strange thing is, that when i add another Provider, this provider will not create the error...

Comment: I would suggest updating your API provider by commenting everything but the boiler plate and see if the error goes away.  then uncomment things until you discover the issue. Without seeing everything I would think there is something fishy in the provider.ts

Comment: Your error message is referring to "SettingsPage", but you don't show us that page. Can you show SettingsPage?

Comment: are you importing any pages in ApiProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working, thanks for the comments.
The Problem was, that in the ApiProvider I was referencing a GlobalvarProvider, which was importing the DocsPage.ts, to be able to add it to the Menu List. 
`Removing this reference got rid of this error`